# Search function with php PDO and mysql

Tags: php, html

I'm Working on a Webshop for a School Project. The website is done and works as intended. Except for the Search function, which works but does something weird.

This is the Code from my Search Page

```
<?php
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$user_id));

    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(isset($_POST['btn-offer']))
    {
            try
            {
                $auth_user->redirect('offer.php');
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }   
    }
?>
<form method="post" class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Enter an Item"/> <br />
                <button type="Search" name="btn-search">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;Search
                </button>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <?php
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                else if(isset($_GET['search'])){
                    //$search_term = $_SESSION['search_term'];
                    $stmt = $user_req->runQuery("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE item LIKE :search");
                    $stmt->bindValue(":search","%".$_SESSION['search_term']."%");
                    $stmt->execute();

                    while($userReq=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        ?><h6> Request ID </h6><?php echo($userReq['id']);  ?> <br /><br /> <?php
                        ?><h6> Requested Item </h6><?php echo($userReq['Item']);  ?> <br /><br /> <?php
                        ?><h6> Requested Price </h6><?php echo($userReq['price']);  ?> <br /><br /> <?php
                        ?><h6> Requested Quantity </h6><?php echo($userReq['quantity']);  ?> <br /><br /> <?php
                        ?><h6> Subject </h6><?php echo($userReq['subject']);  ?> <br /><br /> <?php
                        ?><h6> Description </h6><?php echo($userReq['descr']);
                        ?>
                        <br />
                        <form action="offer.php" method="post" class="form-signin">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="offer_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userReq['id']); ?>"/> <br />
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="offer_item" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userReq['Item']); ?>"/> <br />
                        <button type="Search" name="btn-offer">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;Create Offer
                        </button>
                        </form>
                        <form action="all_offers.php" method="post" class="form-signin">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="offer_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userReq['id']); ?>"/> <br />
                            <button type="Search" name="btn-show">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;Show Offers
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <hr />
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            <br />
        </form>
```

It displays everything as desired (all entries containing the search input).
But if i click on Create Offer, the hidden Input Types gets passed to my Search function just once. It wont update it with the new hidden variables if i click on another create offer button.

Offer.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['offer_id']))
    {
        $_SESSION['off_rid'] = $_POST['offer_id'];
        $_SESSION['offer_item'] = $_POST['offer_item'];
    }
?>
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create Offer for Request ID <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['off_rid']); ?></h2><hr />
        <form method="post" class="form-signin">  
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="off_rid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['off_rid']); ?>"/> <br />         
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Requested Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="off_item" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['offer_item']); ?>" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['offer_item']);}?>" readonly/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="off_price" placeholder="Enter a Price" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $off_price;}?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="off_quant" placeholder="Enter the Quantity" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $off_quant;}?>" />
            </div>

            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="btn-createoffer">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;Post Offer
                </button>
            </div>
            <?php
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                else if(isset($_GET['posted'])){
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> &nbsp; Successfully submitted the Offer!
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            <br />
        </form>
```

If i search for every entry containing "ni" i get all the entries, the hidden Inputtypes are also correct.

If i click on create offer it should write the id and the item on the redirected Page but it only works once. if i go back and search another item it still displays the info from the first item i created an offer.

Can anybody point out what i'm doing wrong. I'm stuck on this Problem since a few days and just cant figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your problem is with HTML rather than SQL

Comment: not really. The problem comes from the PHP site and not from the HTML part. I know the problem doesnt originate from the SQL tho.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work this way. You are supposed to ask a question, not make someone to do it for you

Comment: You seem rather well versed with php. i guess you could help me out rather fast. sadly you chose not to.